# How can I properly convert this code into while loop one?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, average

So I made this code so I could calculate the average grade of a subject with a List and using  the For loop but I am wondering if there is also a way to make the same process but using While Loop. If so, how?

```
mathavg=[[3.5],[3.7],[4],[4.2],[3.6]]
m = 0
for grade1 in mathavg:
    m += sum(grade1)

print("The average score for the subject of Mathematics is: ",m / len(mathavg))
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Any particular reason? A while loop isn't a better choice.

Comment: Any `for` loop can be mechanically converted to a `while` loop, but there's a *reason* the `for` loop exists. (That said, you don't need an explicit loop statement at all: `m = sum(x for gs in mathavg for x in gs)`.)

Comment: Even shorter (though not really recommended) is `sum(sum(mathavg, []))`.

Comment: Along those lines, though, you can use `itertools.chain`: `m = sum(chain.from_iterable(mathavg))`

Comment: Did you get a satisfying answer. If yes, then please select one.  If not,then please say so. perhaps I can give you a helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Without any reason for why, the best I could say is just emulating a for loop with a while loop.

```
mathavg=[[3.5],[3.7],[4],[4.2],[3.6]]
m = 0
i = 0
while i < len(mathavg):
    m += sum(mathavg[i])
    i += 1
```

Although you could use comprehension either way.

```
m = sum([sum(i) for i in mathavg])
```

Comment: Just a question, on the convertion you made how can I make it so It could print out the average of those 5 grades? I tried printing out "i" but seems like it was not possible. I am still new to python so I am trying to understand the codes better. Thank you!

Comment: Just with the `print("The average score for the subject of Mathematics is: ",m / len(mathavg))` you had in your original. In both of these, `m` is being set to the same value as in your original.

Comment: Yeah but it seems like is printing 5 different answers but none of them is correct. Is there any reason why is this happening ?

Comment: You have to print `m / len(mathavg)` after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `mathavg`, remove item in each iteration, until it's empty:

```
mathavg=[[3.5],[3.7],[4],[4.2],[3.6]]
m = 0
while mathavg:
    grade = mathavg.pop()
    m += sum(grade1)

print("The average score for the subject of Mathematics is: ",m / len(mathavg))
```

or iterate over the indices:

```
mathavg=[[3.5],[3.7],[4],[4.2],[3.6]]
m = 0
i = 0
while i < len(mathavg):
    m += sum(mathavg[i])
    i += 1
```